# How to get possible words from a string using forward traversal only- Python

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter


def possiblewords(input, charset):
    # traverse words in list one by one
    for word in input:
        # convert word into dictionary
        dict = Counter(word)
        # now check all keys of corrent word are present in given character set
        flag = 1
        for key in  dict.keys():
            if key not in charset:
                flag = 0
        # if all keys are present (flag = 1) then print the word
        if flag == 1:
            print(word)

# Driver program


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = [ 'nipple','apple','pine','pile']
    str = "pineapple"
    charset = list(str)
    possiblewords(input, charset)
```

**The program above gives output as "pin, apple, pine, pile, nipple"**

I want to change the program it will give result through forward traversal of letters only. It means when I use **str="pineapple",** I want only the results **"pine, apple"**. But this programm gives other possible words using the letters of the words "pineapple". I know that by removing words nipple, and pile this would be ok. But I have to define all the words there. How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find method of python.

```
def possiblewords(input, charset):
    for word in input:
        if charset.find(word) != -1:
            print(word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = [ 'nipple','apple','pine','pile']
    str = "pineapple"
    # Do not convert string to list
    possiblewords(input, str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as

```
from collections import Counter

def possiblewords(input, charset):
    # traverse words in list one by one
    for word in input:
        if str.find(word) != -1:
            print (word)

# Driver program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = [ 'nipple','apple','pine','pile']
    str = "pineapple"
    possiblewords(input, str)
```